# Bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div class="baslik baslik1 baslik2 "> <nav class="navbar bg-light navbar-light navbar-expand-sm sticky-top "> <a href="./index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/512x512logo.png" alt="fenerbahçe logo" width="20%"></a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button> <div class="title title1 title2"> <h1 style="font-size: 40px;"class="navbar-text ml-5 mx-5">FENERİN SESİ</h1> <br> <small class="mx-4 ">Fenerbahçe Spor Kulübü Taraftar Platformu</small> <br> <div class="alt-cizgi alt-cizgi1 alt-cizgi2 title"></div> <div class="sosyal-medya-logolar"> <a href="#" onclick="openInNewTab('https://www.facebook.com/fenerbahce'); return false;"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg" style="color: #043d9f;"></i></a> <a href="#" onclick="openInNewTab('https://www.twitter.com/fenerbahce'); return false;"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg" style="color: #043d9f;"></i></a> <a href="#" onclick="openInNewTab('https://www.instagram.com/fenerbahce'); return false;"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg" style="color: #043d9f;"></i></a> <a href="#" onclick="openInNewTab('https://www.youtube.com/fenerbahce'); return false;"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-lg" style="color: #043d9f;"></i></a> </div> </div> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent"> <div class="dropdown"> <ul class="navbar-nav"> <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> BRANŞLAR </a> <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fal fa-futbol" style="color: #000000;"></i> Futbol</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fal fa-basketball-ball" style="color: #000000;"></i> Basketbol</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fal fa-volleyball-ball" style="color: #000000;"></i> Voleybol</a> </div> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a> </li> </ul> </div> </div> </nav> </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

I am using Bootstrap 4. When I switch to mobile view, the button appears, but when I click it, it does not open.

Answer (score 0):

The data-toggle of the button to open the collapsed nav content must match the element with class `navbar-collapse`.

```html
<button data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">
```

Comment: Note: I replaced `data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"` (which references a non-existent id) with `data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"`.